# Unquoted date in first column pf CSV for Python/Pandas read_csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Incoming CSV from American Express download looks like below.  (I would prefer each field has quotes around it, but it doesn't.  It is treating the quoted long number in the second CSV column as the first column in the Pandas data frame, i.e.  320193480240275508 as my "Date" column:

> 12/13/19,'320193480240275508',Alamo Rent A Car,John
>   Doe,-12345,178.62,Travel-Vehicle Rental,DEBIT,

```
colnames = ['Date', 'TransNum', 'Payee', 'NotUsed4', 'NotUsed5', 'Amount', 'AmexCategory', 'DebitCredit']
df = pd.read_csv(filenameIn, names=colnames, header=0, delimiter=",")
delimiter=",")
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 15)
pd.set_option('display.width', 200)
print (df)
print (df.values)
```

> Start
>                             Date  ... DebitCredit 12/13/19  '320193480240275508'  ...         NaN

I have a routine to reformat the date ( to handle things like 1/3/19, and to add the century).  It is called like this:

```
df['Date'][j] = reformatAmexDate2(df['Date'][j])
```

That routine shows the date as follows:

```
def reformatAmexDate2(oldDate):
    print ("oldDate=" + oldDate)
```

> oldDate='320193480240275508'

I saw this post which recommended dayfirst=True, and added that, but same result.  I never even told Pandas that column 1 is a date, so it should treat it as text I believe.

Comment: is it the order of columns that read_csv is changing or replacing/interchanging values of columns?

Comment: Can you re-word that, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: sorry, i am not able to understand the problem on hand, you said  'It is treating the quoted long number in the second CSV column as the first column in the Pandas data frame' what does that mean you want date column as your first? or index?

Comment: It's a csv, everything between commas should be one field, thus the date should be field 1, the 320193480240275508 should be TransNum etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the data, I didn't notice the comma after the column value, i.e. the comma after "DEBIT,"

```
12/13/19,'320193480240275508',Alamo Rent A Car,John Doe,-12345,178.62,Travel-Vehicle Rental,DEBIT,
```

I just added another column at the end of  my columns array:

```
colnames = ['Date', 'TransNum', 'Payee', 'NotUsed4', 'NotUsed5', 'Amount', 'AmexCategory', 'DebitCredit','NotUsed9']
```

and life is wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, the problem seems to be `name=colnames`, it sets new names for your columns being read from csv file, as you are trying to read specific columns from csv file, you can use `usecol`

```
df = pd.read_csv(filenameIn,usecols=colnames, header=0, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: I will read more on the difference later, but switching to usecols now gives this error:  "columns expected but not found: {missing}".format(missing=missing)
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['NotUsed5', 'AmexCategory', 'NotUsed4', 'DebitCredit', 'Payee', 'TransNum'].  I think it's still confused that some fields don't have the single quotes around them. Names= worked fine for the previous files I downloaded from American Express, before they changed the format.

Comment: you can skip the usecols and read the whole file, then use df.columns to list out the column names, see if there are some missing

Comment: Now I'm more confused.  I did have a header line in the file, and just took it out.  I want to use my own column names.  If I do as you said, it shows the first row of data as column names: Index(['12/22/19', ''320193570416107042'', 'SOMEPAYYNAME', 'NEAL WALTERS', '-xxxxx', '9.99', 'Business Services-Advertising Services', 'DEBIT', 'Unnamed: 8'], dtype='object').  So why won't it parse the date correctly in my scenario?

Comment: I found an extra comma at the end of their data, so just added another column name to my array of columns.